# Importing 'alt' and 'title' fields does not work for custom image migration

Tags: entities, media, migrations

I'm doing a D7->8 custom migration. While images (even multiple) get imported fine via a separate file migration based on d7_file, 'alt' and 'title' tags are not migrated at all.
The images are imported via

```
field_galerie:
  plugin: iterator
  source: field_galerie
  process:
    target_id:
      plugin: migration
      migration: luxus_files
      source: fid
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only mapping the fid there - you need to also map the alt and title for them to come over:

```
field_galerie:
  plugin: iterator
  source: field_galerie
  process:
    target_id:
      plugin: migration
      migration: luxus_files
      source: fid
    alt: alt
    title: title
```